# Which Shaivite sects are dualistic?

Tags: shaivism, dvaita

Most Shaivite sects are Advaitin whereas some Shaivites, especially Acharya Srikantha's followers in South India follow Vishistadvaita. Are there any Shaivite sects that are dualistic?

Comment: What is the srikantha sect ? What is it known as ?

Comment: SadaShiva revealed 3 types of Aagams. Bheda, BhedAbheda and Abheda. Bheda Aagams are dualistic 10 in number like Kamika, Sukshma etc.. They are Shaiva Siddhantins. BhedAbheda are 18 in number like Parameswara, Kirana etc..., They are VeeraShaivas. Abheda are 64 Bhairava Aagams like RudraYamala, VishnuYamala etc... , They are Kashmiri Shaivas.

Comment: @RakeshJoshi idk the actual name of the sect.

Comment: @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury yes it's better if you look.at.them without the glasses of vedanta.

Comment: @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury if you prefer to talk in agama room to.discuss